# Showing multi list and drop down hierachy on page

Tags: users, dropdown, multi-selection, roles

We are dealing with Roles and assigning users to the Roles. Some of Roles which are Admin are not dependant on Context ( Environment - Production, Demo, Developement ), and some ( portal roles) are dependant on Context. So
in the flow, we chose a Role and assign Users as below :

Flow : 
1. User selects a role from left 
2. Then selects a context 
3. Select Users from Available users list and assign to Role

[image]

Portal Role having single context

[image]

Portal Role having multiple Contexts ,you can select from dropdown and then assign Users

[image]

So any advice or suggestions to make it more understandable the flow to users? This was created by other designer and I have to modify it to make it better.

Comment: 'Making the flow more understandable doesn't always mean re-designing whole the page. Besides not possible to assume the flow without seeing the prior and following screens, if you specifically want re-designing of your current page, I also mind that you may achieve this simply coloring the existing pages instead.

Comment: Modify in the sense, its clear to the user and remove the inconsistency part

Answer (score 2):

I think Assigned Users's list should come first. Before adding anyone new to the list, a user is supposed to scan the list of those who are currently assigned. The two sections should also be separated more clearly, perhaps by a border in between, to mean two different tasks.

The term 'Available Users' is a little vague. It leaves the user guessing - available for what. If it is about adding a new user to the assigned list, it could just read 'Add New To The List' or something more direct and suitable.

The Save and Cancel buttons can be moved and fixed to the top to be persistently visible.

If 'Context' is a mandatory field, it should be marked as mandatory with an asterisk or in some other way.

Not sure how the Close button at the top right corner helps. That could probably be removed.

Also it will help to increase affordance on clickable links.

Answer (score 1):

1. The current flow appears clear.
2. Would recommend following consistent naming - instead of "Add User", label the button as "Assign User"
3. Similarly, rename "Available Users" to "Unassigned Users". Consequently, Unassigned Users + Assign Button = Assigned Users

Answer (score 1):

the right to left flow seems well done, this pattern is quite common so users should be familiar with it. not sure why the menu on the far left needs to be so wide. it could possible interfere with visual hierarchy. making that column more narrow could help the user focus on the most important element here which is the users list and assigned users box.